# SiriKit Media Intents

Tags: ios, swift, sirikit

I am trying to implement media intents(INPlayMediaIntentHandling), but nothing seems to work, the handlers are not being called nothing is executing, my aim is to capture what is being said to Siri ex: - Hey Siri, play Hero in MyApp

This is my intents handler -

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, INPlayMediaIntentHandling {
    
    func handle(intent: INPlayMediaIntent, completion: @escaping (INPlayMediaIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        if let identifier = intent.mediaSearch?.mediaIdentifier {
            print(identifier)
        }
        print("Aloha")
        completion(INPlayMediaIntentResponse(code: .continueInApp, userActivity: nil))
    }
    
    func resolveMediaItems(for intent: INPlayMediaIntent, with completion: @escaping ([INPlayMediaMediaItemResolutionResult]) -> Void) {
        if let identifier = intent.mediaSearch?.mediaIdentifier {
            print(identifier)
        }
        print("Aloha")
        completion([INPlayMediaMediaItemResolutionResult.unsupported()])
    }
}
```

I do have this method in AppDelegete -

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handle intent: INIntent, completionHandler: @escaping (INIntentResponse) -> Void) {
        guard let playMediaIntent = intent as? INPlayMediaIntent else {
            completionHandler(INPlayMediaIntentResponse(code: .failure, userActivity: nil))
            return
        }
        print("Print")
        print(playMediaIntent.mediaSearch?.mediaIdentifier ?? "Print")
    }
```

not sure what am doing wrong, any help is appreciated!!